# Struggling with MDL textfields within hidden blocks

Tags: jquery, html, forms, material-design-lite

I should probably preface this by saying I'm not great at HTML, jQuery or CSS. I get most things done by Googling something approximating what I'm after, trying to understand how that works and then adapting it to what I want.

I'm trying to create an HTML form asking people to list how many people they're bringing, their names and their drinking preferences. I'm using Google's Material Design Lite to make it look extra snazzy, but I've ran in to a problem where I can't get textfields to show up (I'm using some CSS and jQuery trickery to only show name fields and such for the number of selected guests, which you can see I've found elsewhere StackOverflow...)

This is the jQuery:

```
$("#dropDown").change(function(){
  //Var x is equal to the number selected.
  var x = parseInt($(this).val());
  //Element is equal to the children of box-container
  var element = $("#box-container").children();
  //Set all children to display as none. (This hides them).
  $(element).css({display:"none"});
  //Loop for as many times as selected. (The value of x).
  for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
    //Show each child by displaying as block.
    $(element[i]).fadeIn(700);
    }
});
```

And this is the MDL element that doesn't show up:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="Demo" id="demo" />
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="demo">Name...</label>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen to show the whole thing, and the problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meJWem

The first line in the output is just to show what it's supposed to look like, then if you select a number of guests, you'll see that only the radio buttons will show for the first 2 entries and not the textfield. I left the 3 entry as plain HTML fields just to show what I'm after.
Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working as I'm expecting it to? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your style to:

```
.boxes>div {
    display: none;
}
```

This limits it so it applies to only the divs that are direct children of the div with `class="boxes"`. What you have applies the style to all divs that are descendants of the div with `class="boxes"`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkvL0tt9/)

---

You could also use the `:lt()` selector, instead of looping.

```
$("#dropDown").change(function(){
    var x = parseInt($(this).val());

    var $elements = $("#box-container").children();

    $elements.hide().filter(':lt(' + x + ')').fadeIn(700);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkvL0tt9/1/)

Comment: That works great, thank you! I suspected it was something silly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your text fields remain hidden because of the CSS rule

```
.boxes div {
    display: none;
}
```

That rule says that *any* children of the `.boxes` element, not just immediate children (in other words, grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc.) are not displayed. That includes the `<div>` elements that hold the text inputs. (They're of class `mdl-textfield`)

When your JavaScript executes, you're only fading in the immediate children of the `#box-container`. That has no effect on the text field `<div>` elements since those elements are "grandchildren" of the `.boxes` container.

This problem doesn't affect the third option because there you're using standard `<input>` elements instead of the MDL `<div>` and the CSS rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense.